# Building an ifttt clone

Tags: python, architecture, triggers, action, system

For learning purposes I would very much like to build a ifttt clone.

I can code on my own, at least in python and usually come up with good solutions for my own problems. The problem is I don't have a clue where to start to build such a system so, I'm interested in the architecture for a a dynamic system like this, with different triggers and having different actions?

Thanks!

EDIT: to make the question a bit easier.

Comment: This is far too broad to be an answerable question

Comment: @mhlester I edited my question in an attempt to simplify it a bit. Anyway, any idea where I should start at least?

Comment: Take a look at [huginn at github](https://github.com/cantino/huginn "huginn"). The same that you want to code, but in ruby.

Comment: Take a look at [pimatic](https://github.com/pimatic/pimatic) at github. The same that you want to code, but in Node.js.

Comment: For anyone looking to do the same, take a look at [Trigger Happy](https://github.com/push-things/django-th), it's built using Python and Django I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The things IFTTT does can be broken down into these things:
- check if stuff happened
- receive triggers that stuff happened
- send requests to APIs
- connect "stuff happening" to API requests

The most straightforward one is "send requests to APIs" so I suggest you start there. Try, with code, to talk to APIs of different websites: Twitter, Instagram, Dropbox, Facebook etc. Definitely use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for this.

The "check if stuff happened" is a little harder, here you periodically poll services (like APIs) to see if the state on the other side has changed. If stuff has changed (and the stuff that has changed is relevant for the recipe) now we know. We can use this knowledge to fire the "send requests to APIs". You can probably use Requests for this too.

The "receive information that stuff happened" is probably the hardest one. It's very similar to "check if stuff happened" but this is passive instead of active. Look into the publish/subscribe pattern and [PubSubHubbub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub).

Connect them together. Now basically you want to create recipes that a user can somehow define. I'd start just hardcoding them at first, then later making it configurable through a web interface. So basically: check if stuff changed, if so, send a request to an API. Then later you can iterate over all the recipes and check what you need to check for each recipe, if stuff happened send the requests defined in the recipe. Then finally create a webapplication including forms in which users can define recipes. I advise using some kind of framework for this, Django is popular, as is Flask.

Good luck!